# how to delete relationship between two tables?

Tags: sql

I created two tables How to delete relationship between them in sql code;

`Course` table:

```
create table course 
(
     course_id int primary key identity (1,1),
     course_name varchar(40)
);
```

`Employee` table:

```
create table employee 
(
     emp_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
     fname varchar(30),
     course_id int 
         foreign key references course (course_id)
);
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for **SQL Server** - then you can find out the name of the FK constraint using this statement:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('employee')
AND referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID('course')
```

and once you have that FK constraint name, you can use the usual

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.employee DROP CONSTRAINT (name of the FK constraint)
```

This will be an arbitrary, system-generated name (something like `FK__employee__cours__7EB7AD3A` or similar) - and this is the reason I'd recommend to **always** explicitly name your constraints - like this:

```
create table employee 
(
     emp_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
     fname varchar(30),
     course_id int 
         constraint fk_employee_course
         foreign key references course (course_id)
);
```

Now, you **know** what the name of that FK constraint is - you **named** it `fk_employee_course`. This is also beneficial if you get any error messages about FK constraint violations - if that name is **intuitive** and obvious, then you'll know what went wrong